# Pytest: Why is my mocked functions not called?

Tags: unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest

I'm trying to write a unit test for my code. But I get the assertion error that the mock is not being called. How to fix this problem?

In my `code.py`

```py
from SDK import ManagementClient

def init_client():
    MGMT_CLIENT = ManagementClient(credentials) 
    # ManagementClient is an imported module, MGMT_CLIENT is a global variable
    

def add_db(ids):
    for id in ids:
        db_connection = MGMT_CLIENT.databases
        db_connection.database_operations.create()
```

In `test.py`

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def database_operations_mock():
    with mock.patch("code.MGMT_CLIENT.databases") as database_operations_mock:
        yield database_operations_mock

@pytest.fixutre
def client_mock():
        with mock.patch("code.ManagementClient") as client_mock:
        yield client_mock


def test_add():
    # prepare test data
    ids_mock = ['1','2'] 
    # update global variable for code.py to run add_db() 
    code.MGMT_CLIENT = client_mock()  
    # run actual functions
    code.add_db(ids_mock)  
    assert database_operations_mock.call_count == len(ids_mock)
```

I got this error:

```sh
>       assert database_operations_mock.call_count == len(ids_mock)
E       assert 0 == 2
E         +0
E         -2
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need the second mock. Also I don't think you quite understand how calls to mocks work, the call count corresponds to the *method* called, and in your case it is `db_connection.database_operations.create`. Also, you can not update a global variable in your actual python scripts from your test script, Python does not work like that. Your code should look like this if I understand correctly.

```
def test_add(client_mock):
    # prepare test data
    ids_mock = ['1','2']
    # make the mock return itself when we call ManagementClient(credentials)
    # this will allow us to validate call counts
    client_mock.return_value = client_mock
    # since ManagementClient is mocked the `add_db` function should already call the mock
    code.add_db(ids_mock)
    # we have to check that `create` is being called
    assert client_mock.databases.database_operations.create == len(ids_mock)
```